# Code Blocks gives me following error upon execution of code(even parity hamming code)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PecXN.png)[image: This is the message i receive after giving input]

> This is what it shows in the build log:

Checking for existence: C:\CodeBlocks\hammingcodeven.exe
Executing: '"C:\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\CodeBlocks\hammingcodeven.exe"' (in 'C:\CodeBlocks')
Set variable: PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\mahek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 54 second(s))

> This is the code to find binary value of m bit code after using an even parity hamming code

```cpp
    #include<iostream>
    #include<math.h>
    using namespace std;

    class data
    {
        int A[50],m,r,ps[6],B[6][56],final[56];
    public:
        void show();
        void input();
        void findr();
        void findps();
        void binary();
        void findfinal();
    };
    void data::input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter length of frame:";
        cin>>m;
        cout<<"Enter frame:";
        for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
        {
            cin>>A[i];
        }
        findr();

    }
     void data::findr()
    {
        r=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
        {
            int x=pow(2,i);

            if(x>(m+i+1))
            {
                r=i;

                break;
            }
        }
        if(r==0)
            cout<<"Error";
        binary();
    }
    void data::binary()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=m+r;i++)
        {
            int h=i;
            for(int j=r;j>=1;j--)
            {
                B[i][j]=h%2;
                h=h/2;
            }

        }
        findps();
    }
    void data::findps()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=r;i++)
            ps[i]=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=m+r;i++)
        {
           for(int j=1;j<=r;j++)
           {
               ps[j]=ps[j]^B[i][j];

           }
        }
        findfinal();
    }
    void data::findfinal()
    {

        for(int i=1,j=1;i<=m+r,j<=r;i++,j*=2)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                final[i]=ps[j];
            }
            else
                final[i]=A[i];
        }
    }
    void data::show()
    {
        cout<<"Input:";
        for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
            cout<<A[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Output:";
        for(int i=1;i<=m+r;i++)
            cout<<final[i]<<" ";

    }

    int main()
    {
        data obj;
        obj.input();
        obj.show();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: Try creating a [mre], as this will help focus debugging efforts. See what you can eliminate from your code without eliminating the crash. Also, hardcode values instead of relying on user input.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop of the function `binary()`, the variable i can go as high as `m + r`. In your example, m is 8, so `m + r` is at least 9. However, i is used to index the first dimension of B, which has a sizr of six. Accessing B outside of its defined size results in reading/writing other memory on the stack, resulting in undefined behavior. To help with this, you could dynamically allocate your fields with the needed size. I also strongly recommend giving your fields meaningful names to help people understand what your code is trying to do.

Furthermore, you are indexing arrays incorrectly. In C++ and many other languages, arrays are zero indexed, meaning that the first value of an array A of size n is at A[0] and the last value is at A[n-1].